# Ising Model - Atom Vibration Simulation in Scala

Tags: scala, simulation, physics

I am an experienced Java developer (12+ years) and have recently switched to Scala and I love it. However I feel not comfy yet and I have a feeling that I might use to many paradigms from the good old Java days.

That's why I would like to start with some simple code I wrote while viewing a Stanford Seminar on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/hvIptUuUCdU?t=940) with the Topic "Deep Learning for Dummies". I tried to simulate the results presented in minute [~15:40](https://youtu.be/hvIptUuUCdU?t=940).

Basically the code simulates vibration of atoms in the Ising Model in parallel, and gives a brief summary of how often a particular stable state has been reached.

Everything works as expected and it proves the numbers shown in the presentation.

No code is missing below in order to work and I did not use third party libs.

### **deeplearning/IsingModelSmall.scala**

```
package deeplearning

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import deeplearning.AtomState.AtomState
import deeplearning.AtomState._


/**
  * Created by Julian Liebl on 25.11.15.
  *
  * All inspiration taken from youtu.be/hvIptUuUCdU. This class reproduces and proves the result shown in minute ~15:40.
  */
class IsingModelSmall {
  case class MinMax(val min:Double, val max:Double)

  val x1 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
  val x2 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
  val x3 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
  val x4 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
  val x5 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
  val x6 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
  val x7 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
  val x8 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))

  /**
    * Calculates the stable state of a Ising Model according to youtu.be/hvIptUuUCdU.
    * It takes a random atom from the model as parameter and parses from there all atoms and sub(n) atoms it is
    * connected to.
    *
    *
    * Here is an example how the stable state is calculated:
    *
    * Model =  a1(Up) <- w1(-50) -> a2(Down) <- w2(99) -> a3(Down)
    *       => x = -((a1 * w1 * a2) + (a2 * w2 * a3))
    *       => x = -((1 * -50 * -1) + (-1 * 99 * -1))
    *       => x = -(50 + 99)
    *       => x = -
    *
    * @param atom A random atom form the model. Needs at least one connection. Otherwise stable state will be zero.
    * @return stable state value
    */
  def calcStableState(atom:Atom, touchedAtoms:Set[Atom] = Set()): Double ={
    var sum:Double = 0

    val a1v = getAtomStateValue(atom.atomState)
    atom.getConnections().foreach(connection => {
      val connectedAtom = connection.connectedAtom

      if(!(touchedAtoms contains connectedAtom)){
        val a2v = getAtomStateValue(connectedAtom.atomState)

        sum += a1v * a2v * connection.weight

        sum += calcStableState(connectedAtom, touchedAtoms + atom)
      }
    })

    - sum
  }

  /**
    * Retrieves the min and max weight for all atom connections in a model.
    * It takes a random atom from the model as parameter and parses from there all connections and sub(n) connections.
    *
    *
    * Example:
    *
    * Model =  a1(Up) <- w1(-50) -> a2(Down) <- w2(99) -> a3(Down) <- w3(20) -> a4(Up)
    *       => min = -50
    *       => max =  99
    *
    * @param atom A random atom form the model. Needs at least one connection. Otherwise min and max will be zero.
    * @return min and max weight
    */
  def getMinMaxWeight(atom:Atom, touchedAtoms:Set[Atom] = Set()): MinMax ={
    var minMax:MinMax = MinMax(0,0)

    atom.getConnections().foreach(connection => {
      val connectedAtom = connection.connectedAtom

      if(!(touchedAtoms contains connectedAtom)){
        val currentWeight = connection.weight

        if (currentWeight < minMax.min){
          minMax = minMax.copy(min = currentWeight)
        }
        else if (currentWeight > minMax.max) {
          minMax = minMax.copy(max = currentWeight)
        }

        val provisionalMinMax = getMinMaxWeight(connectedAtom, touchedAtoms + atom)
        if(provisionalMinMax.min < minMax.min) minMax = minMax.copy(min = provisionalMinMax.min)
        if(provisionalMinMax.max > minMax.max) minMax = minMax.copy(max = provisionalMinMax.max)
      }
    })

    minMax
  }

  /**
    * Atom vibration simulation.
    * It takes a random atom from the model as parameter and parses from there all connections. Simulating a random
    * initial atom state and regarding probability of all connections and sub connections. Resulting in the same
    * connections but may be with different states then before.
    *
    * @param atom A random atom form the model. Needs at least one connection. Otherwise the given atom will just be
    *             returned.
    * @return The new atom with the same connections but eventually different states.
    */
  def vibrate(atom:Atom): Atom ={
    var touchedAtoms:Set[Atom] = scala.collection.immutable.Set()

    val currentMinMaxWeight = getMinMaxWeight(atom)

    val minWeight = currentMinMaxWeight.min
    val maxWeight = currentMinMaxWeight.max

    val weightRange = if(Math.abs(minWeight) > Math.abs(maxWeight)) Math.abs(minWeight) else Math.abs(maxWeight)
    val scaledWeightRange = weightRange * 1.2

    val random = scala.util.Random

    def vibrateInner(innerAtom:Atom, currentAtomState:AtomState):Atom ={
      val newAtom = new Atom(currentAtomState)

      touchedAtoms += newAtom

      innerAtom.getConnections().foreach(connection => {
        val connectedAtom = connection.connectedAtom
        connectedAtom.removeConnection(innerAtom)

        if(!(touchedAtoms contains connectedAtom)){
          val weight = connection.weight

          val probability = Math.abs(weight) / scaledWeightRange
          val randomDouble = random.nextDouble()
          val isFollowing = probability - randomDouble >= 0

          if(weight != 0){
            var connectedAtomState:AtomState = null

            if(weight < 0) {
              connectedAtomState = if (isFollowing) getOppositeState(currentAtomState) else currentAtomState
            }else{
              connectedAtomState = if (isFollowing) currentAtomState else getOppositeState(currentAtomState)
            }

            connectedAtom.atomState = connectedAtomState

            newAtom.fuse(connection.weight, vibrateInner(connectedAtom, connectedAtomState))
          }else{
            println("Error: Weight should never be 0!")
            return newAtom
          }
        }
      })

      newAtom
    }

    vibrateInner(atom, getRandomAtomState())
  }
}


object IsingModelSmall{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val model = new IsingModelSmall

    println("E(x1,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x1))
    println("E(x2,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x2))
    println("E(x3,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x3))
    println("E(x4,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x4))
    println("E(x5,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x5))
    println("E(x6,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x6))
    println("E(x7,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x7))
    println("E(x8,w) = " + model.calcStableState(model.x8))

    println(model.getMinMaxWeight(model.x1))

    val vibrationLoopCount:Int = 10000
    val atomicLoopIndex = new AtomicInteger()
    println("Simulating vibration of atom " + vibrationLoopCount + " times.")

    val statesToCount = (1 to vibrationLoopCount).toTraversable.par.map(loopIndex => {
      val vibratedX1 = model.vibrate(model.x1)

      if(atomicLoopIndex.incrementAndGet() % 10000 == 0) print("\r" + atomicLoopIndex.get())

      model.calcStableState(vibratedX1)
    }).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

    println("\r" + atomicLoopIndex.get())

    val states = statesToCount.keySet.toList.sorted

    states.foreach(state => println(state + "\t: " + statesToCount.get(state).get))
  }
}
```

### **deeplearning/Atom.scala**

```
package deeplearning

import deeplearning.AtomState.AtomState

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

/**
  * Created by Julian Liebl on 26.11.15.
  *
  * Class which represents an atom in the Ising Model.
  */
class Atom(var atomState: AtomState) {
  var connections:ListBuffer[AtomConnection] = ListBuffer()

  def addConnection(atomConnection: AtomConnection): Unit ={
    connections += atomConnection
  }

  def removeConnection(atomConnection: AtomConnection): Unit ={
    connections -= atomConnection
  }

  def removeConnection(atom:Atom): Unit ={
    connections = connections.filter(connection => !(connection.connectedAtom equals atom))
  }

  def removeConnections(atoms:Seq[Atom]): Unit ={
    connections = connections.filter(connection => !(atoms contains connection.connectedAtom))
  }

  def getConnections(): Seq[AtomConnection]  ={
    connections
  }

  /**
    * Creates a weighted connection between the atom and anotherAtom. Returns the other atom in order to be able to
    * chain the creation of a model.
    *
    * @param weight weight of the connection
    * @param otherAtom other atom
    * @return other atom
    */
  def fuse(weight:Double, otherAtom:Atom): Atom ={
    AtomConnection.fuse(this, otherAtom, weight)

    otherAtom
  }
}
```

### **deeplearning/AtomConnection.scala**

```
package deeplearning

/**
  * Created by Julian Liebl on 26.11.15.
  *
  * Class which represents an atom connection in the Ising Model.
  */
case class AtomConnection(connectedAtom:Atom, weight:Double)

object AtomConnection{
  /**
    * Creates a weighted connection between two atoms.
    *
    * @param a1 first atom
    * @param a2 second atom
    * @param weight weight of the connection
    */
  def fuse(a1:Atom, a2:Atom, weight:Double): Unit ={
    a1.addConnection(new AtomConnection(a2, weight))
    a2.addConnection(new AtomConnection(a1, weight))
  }
}
```

### **deeplearning/AtomState.scala**

```
package deeplearning

/**
  * Created by Julian Liebl on 25.11.15.
  *
  * Class which represents an atom state in the Ising Model.
  */
object AtomState extends Enumeration {
  type AtomState = Value
  val Up, Down = Value

  /**
    * Helper method which returns the numerical state value.
    *
    * Up = 1
    * Down = -1
    *
    * @param atomState atom state
    * @return the numerical representation of the atom state
    */
  def getAtomStateValue(atomState: AtomState): Int ={
    if(atomState equals Up) 1 else -1
  }

  /**
    * Helper method which returns a random atom state.
    * @return the random atom state
    */
  def getRandomAtomState(): AtomState ={
    val r = scala.util.Random
    if(r.nextInt(2) equals 0) Up else Down
  }

  /**
    * Helper method which return the opposite atom state.
    *
    * @param atomState atom state
    * @return the opposite atom state
    */
  def getOppositeState(atomState: AtomState) ={
    if(atomState equals Up) Down else Up
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for this interesting question. Generally, your code is quite clean and the years of experience are visible through it. I'm also a Java developer, switching on Scala, that I love more and more.

Here are my observations about this code.

#### `class Atom`

The main thing about it is the usage of `var connections`. [`Var`iables are discouraged in Scala](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false); they should be used in reduced scope without external exposure (`connections` has public access here).

So we can just transform the field into `val`:

```
val connections = ListBuffer[AtomConnection]()
// note that the type declaration with ":" is not necessary here
```

Now we cannot reassign the field, but we can operate on its contents when necessary. `removeConection(Atom)` method would look like this:

```
def removeConnection(atom : Atom): Unit ={
  connections.find(connection => connection.connectedAtom == atom) match {
    case None => {}
    case Some(atomConnection) => { removeConnection(atomConnection) }
  }
}
```

The principle is: when the first `AtomConnection` element is found that contains the specified `Atom`, it redirects to the overloaded `removeConnection` function with this element; otherwise it does nothing.

Please note that the equality is checked with `==`, which is equivalent to Java's `equals`.

The same kind of changes can also be done with `removeConnections(atoms:Seq[Atom])` function, but it doesn't seem to be used throughout the code.

The `getConnections()` function is not necessary at all. It looks like a sort of Java's residue; `val connections` already has public access and the reference is immutable.

Generally, I'm not sure about the validity of the choice to use `var atomState` and the exposed `ListBuffer` for `connections` field in `Atom` class. This sort of mutability is somewhat against Scala's principles, but I don't see yet how to work it around.

#### `class IsingModelSmall`

In `def calcStableState`, `def getMinMaxWeight` and `def vibrateInner` there are similar calls:

```
atom.connections.foreach(connection => {
  val connectedAtom = connection.connectedAtom
  ...
  if(!(touchedAtoms contains connectedAtom)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

They can be refactored into a dedicated function:

```
private def filterNonConnected(atom : Atom, touchedAtoms:Set[Atom]) =
  atom.connections.filter(connection =>
    !(touchedAtoms.contains(connection.connectedAtom))
  ).toList
```

Now the `var sum` counter in `calcStableState` can be eliminated:

```
def calcStableState(atom:Atom, touchedAtoms:Set[Atom] = Set()): Double ={
  val a1v = getAtomStateValue(atom.atomState)
  val sum = filterNonConnected(atom, touchedAtoms).foldLeft(0d)((sum, connection) => {
    val connectedAtom = connection.connectedAtom
    val a2v = getAtomStateValue(connectedAtom.atomState)
    sum + a1v * a2v * connection.weight + calcStableState(connectedAtom, touchedAtoms + atom)
  })
  -sum
}
```

What is done in `calcStableState`: 1) we filter the connections to work on with the refactored `filterNonConnected`; 2) we use the standard `foldLeft` function to calculate the sum. It takes the initial value `0d` and performs the calculation using the current value in `sum`, tupled with each of the filtered `connection`s.

`getMinMaxWeight` function can also be simplified using our refactored `filterNonConnected` and `foldLeft`:

```
def getMinMaxWeight(atom:Atom, touchedAtoms:Set[Atom] = Set()): MinMax ={
  filterNonConnected(atom, touchedAtoms).foldLeft(MinMax(0,0))((curMinMax, connection) => {
    val currentWeight = connection.weight
    val provisionalMinMax = getMinMaxWeight(connection.connectedAtom, touchedAtoms + atom)
    MinMax(List(curMinMax.min, currentWeight, provisionalMinMax.min).min,
           List(curMinMax.max, currentWeight, provisionalMinMax.max).max)
  })
}
```

Please note that there is not a single `if-else` left in this function.

BTW, there is a potential bug in the original implementation. `MinMax` shouldn't be initialized with `(0, 0)`, but rather with `(Double.MaxValue, Double.MinValue)`.

`vibrateInner` function can be refactored using the same principle, bu there will be two more things: 1) the `removeConnection` call needs to be separated into a dedicated loop, for example:

```
innerAtom.connections.foreach(connection => {
  connection.connectedAtom.removeConnection(innerAtom)
})
```

But I'm not sure that from the point of view of design it's a good solution, because it looks like a violation of [LoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). There should be a better approach to solve it.

2) the calculation of `connectedAtomState` should be moved into a separate method, which will allow to eliminate the last `var` remaining in this part of code.

#### `object IsingModelSmall`

In Scala, there is no need to define `def main(args : Array[String])`. A simple extension of `App` would do the job:

```
object IsingModelSmall extends App {
  // the body of the main(args) method to be placed here directly
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much already. I will implement your suggestions. Your are right about the bug. When there is no negative or positiv weight the zeros would cause an error in calculation!

Answer (score 3):

**Lists**

If you have 8 variables that are almost identical, you should group them into a list for order, conciseness and to simplify future changes. I am looking at:

```
val x1 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
val x2 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
val x3 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
val x4 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
val x5 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up))
val x6 = new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down))  .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
val x7 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
val x8 = new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
```

Using a list will also simplify printing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was a bit lazy there. I wrote a comment with code changes -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112079/90723 based on your input.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question!

In scala, it is better to use objects as enum values, since it can be much more powerful and works better with pattern matching. [This article is worth reading.](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html)

```
object AtomState{
  sealed trait EnumVal
  case object Up extends EnumVal
  case object Down extends EnumVal
  val states = Seq(Up, Down)
}
```

Also, to avoid the repetition, you could use a nice idiomatic for loop.

```
val combinations = for {
  as1 <- AtomState.states
  as2 <- AtomState.states
  as3 <- AtomState.states
} yield (as1,as2,as3)

combinations.foreach{println}
```

Prints out:

```
(Up,Up,Up)
(Up,Up,Down)
(Up,Down,Up)
(Up,Down,Down)
(Down,Up,Up)
(Down,Up,Down)
(Down,Down,Up)
(Down,Down,Down)
```

You can see how this could be applied in to yield your 8 variables instead:

```
val atoms = for {
  as1 <- AtomState.states
  as2 <- AtomState.states
  as3 <- AtomState.states
} yield new Atom(as1).fuse(-50, new Atom(as2)).fuse(99, new Atom(as3))
```

If a map is needed, although it feels like a bad practice:

```
val mapped = combinations.zipWithIndex.map{case (combo,index:Int) => ("x"+index,combo) }.toMap
mapped.foreach{println}
```

You zip with the index, then map to a tuples of (key -> value), then convert the tuples to map.

Which prints:

```
(x3,(Up,Down,Down))
(x7,(Down,Down,Down))
(x2,(Up,Down,Up))
(x0,(Up,Up,Up))
(x5,(Down,Up,Down))
(x6,(Down,Down,Up))
(x1,(Up,Up,Down))
(x4,(Down,Up,Up))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my edits so far. I do not want to post a new question yet. According to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c) it is a good solution if it is a descriptive comment and helpful for others.

I put my x1-8 variables in a map instead. It results in a cleaner less duplicated code and simplifies the printing as @Caridorc has [suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112074/90723).

**Map**

```
var atomTemplates:Map[String,Atom] = Map(
  "x1" -> new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up)),
  "x2" -> new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Up)),
  "x3" -> new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up)),
  "x4" -> new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down)),
  "x5" -> new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Up)),
  "x6" -> new Atom(Up)   .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Down)),
  "x7" -> new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Up))   .fuse(99, new Atom(Down)),
  "x8" -> new Atom(Down) .fuse(-50 , new Atom(Down)) .fuse(99, new Atom(Down))
)
```

**Printing**

```
model.atomTemplates.toList.sortBy(_._1).foreach(entry => {
   println("E(" + entry._1 + ",w) = " + model.calcStableState(entry._2))
})
```